# Orders not completing

Tags: expresso-store

I'm running Store 2.0.2 on ExpressionEngine 2.7.1 and am using Paypal Express as my gateway. Orders aren't going through and I can't figure out why. Hoping someone can help.

User is taken over to Paypal with the correct total and can put in all their credit card info and it seems to go through. It sends them back to the site and I see it flash index.php?ACT=28&H=..... And then it redirects to the site's homepage. It *should* take them to the order confirmation page but doesn't.

Store sends an Order Confirmation email to the user (and admins). But the order stays Incomplete and card is never charged.

In the order detail under transactions is says the status is redirected. I don't know what that means (if anything?).

Here's my checkout tag:

```
{exp:store:checkout
    form_class="form-horizontal"
    payment_method="paypal_express"
    return="shop/order/ORDER_HASH"
    error_handling="inline"
    error_delimiters='<span class="help-inline">|</span>'}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try removing your htaccess rules to see if you can complete an order. If it works with no htaccess file then you have a rule that is preventing Store from completing the order.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried. Removed it and submitted another order. Same thing as before :-/

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest v2.2.0? A considerable number of bugs have been fixed since v2.0.2 so it's worth a try. If that doesn't work, can you email support@exp-resso.com so we can take a look at this directly on your server?

Comment: Thanks! I did that as well...I'm corresponding with someone from support now. I've tried several things and nothing has worked yet. But when we figure it out I'll post the solution...in case it would help anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that there was an html file in the root of the site that had a redirect in the header to site/index.php. That redirect was causing issues when Paypal was communicating with the store that payment had been received.

Thanks to Expresso Store support for tracking down the issue!

Comment: Remember to mark your answer as correct.